# Why selenium send_keys is not working but when I type manually it is working?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, sendkeys

I've got following code and issue is that after using 'send_keys' method page is responsing me with message that input is incorrect but when I'm typing it manually it is working fine. Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Thanks

```
      '''<div class="form-group">
  ::before
  <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DocumentNo" Id="DocumentNoLabel" style=NR></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="DocumentNo" name="DocumentNo"
        type="text" value style>
      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DocumentNo"
      data-valmsg-replace='true' id=errorDocNo>
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
        ::after
        </div>
'''



     '''my_data = 'string'
        element.clear()
        element.click()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "DocumentNo").send_keys(my_data)
'''
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "page is responsing me with message that input is incorrect"

Comment: Target the input tag

Comment: I'm sending my_data = 'string' via send_keys() to the input element. Right below the input page is showing "input is incorrect". This message also appears when string is too long or too short. From the other side, when I run this script with pytest it doesn't show this message. Generally what I want to do is to test one scenario multiple times with different data(which is in json file). I stucked a bit on this send_keys() issue.